# OpenIdDict - password flow does not work any more

Tags: openiddict

does anybody know what is happand with password flow. It is work file last week, and today it is no.
We got update form my-get for this library and add a few new columns (Permissions, Properties, Payload and ReferenceId ets.).

New we always got:

```
{
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "This client application is not allowed to use the token endpoint."
```

}

We did not change anything in the test.

So any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with RC2, applications must be granted permissions to be able to use endpoints or flows.

For more information on application permissions, visit https://documentation.openiddict.com/configuration/application-permissions.html.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to official [documentaion:](https://openiddict.github.io/openiddict-documentation/guide/migration.html#if-necessary-adjust-the-permissions-granted-to-your-clients)

> If you don't care about permissions (e.g because you don't have third-party clients), you can instead disable them:

```
 // Register the OpenIddict server handler.
.AddServer(options =>
{
    options.IgnoreEndpointPermissions()
           .IgnoreGrantTypePermissions()
           .IgnoreScopePermissions();
});
```

It fixed my problem.